# How allow input length 0 and >= 6

Tags: html, input, content-length

Currently I have built a password form like this.

```
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password" minlength='6' ng-model="model.password"
         placeholder="Password"
         required/>
```

Here password length is more than 6.
But default users have no password and allow 0 length password.
I have no idea how to do this.
Must look like this(not using javascript)

```
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password" length='0 || > 6' ng-model="model.password"
         placeholder="Password"
         />
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: How can you use `required` and a length of `0`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you are asking the user to enter their current password, there is no need to enforce a particular format. If you are asking them to pick a new password, then you are no longer allowing them to have no password.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use this:

```html
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="Password" pattern="|.{6}.*" />
```

`required` enforces the field must be non-empty. Do not use it.
The number in the code means minimum lenght. See description.

## Description:

Use a `pattern` attribute here. It defines a RegEx (regular expression) that describes the content. The check is done by browser. **Check it also on server-side.**

### Example:

```html
<input pattern="|......+" />
```

Pattern description:

`|` means "or" (Empty string (left side) or `......+` (right side))

`.` means any character (only one)

`.+` means one or more characters.

---

Use more dots (`.`) to set longer string.

---

If you want to use number, use this:

```html
<input pattern="|.{6}.*">
```

The number between `{` and `}` is length.

`.{number}` means a string with fixed length.

`.*` means a string (0 or more characters)